# My issue is when the user is asked to enter the name of the text file they just created, it doesn't recognise the file. Python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, input, txt

I have created a calculator that takes input from the user to create a txt. file and once they are finished with the calculator, they're asked to input the name of the text file they just created to view their calculations. I just seem to be stuck with the user entering the text file to view the results (I'm new to python)

Here is my part of my code:

try:

```
                with open(results+'.txt ', 'a') as results_file:
                    results_file.write(
                        f"\n{number_one} {maths_operation} {number_two} = {output}")
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Whoops! File not found please enter correct file name: ")
            except IOError:
                print("An error occured while opening the file.")
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Invalid input. Please enter an operator value")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(
            "Invalid operator! Use a valid operator '+', '-', '*', '/'. Please try again: ")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Whoops! You cannot divide by zero. Please try again: ")

    # Conditional statements to print the results of that sum and writing it to the text file

reuse = input(
    "Re-use the calculator? Type 'y' to re-use or Type 'n' to view your calculations:")

if reuse == "n":
    while True:
        try:

            view_file = (
                input("To view your calculations, please enter the filename: "))
            # results_file = open('results_file', 'a')
            if view_file == results_file:
                results_file = open(results_file, 'r')
                print(results_file.read(), "/n")
                break
            else:
                raise FileNotFoundError(
                    "Whoops! File not found please enter correct file name: ")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found! Please enter correct file name:  ")
```

When I enter the same name file it doesn't open the file and due to the exception handling I end up in a continuous loop asking for the correct file name. I am not entirely sure when I've gone wrong, but it is definitely somewhere here:

```
 if reuse == "n":
        while True:
            try:

                view_file = (
                    input("To view your calculations, please enter the filename: "))
                # results_file = open('results_file', 'a')
                if view_file == results_file:
                    results_file = open(results_file, 'r')
                    print(results_file.read(), "/n")
                    break
                else:
                    raise FileNotFoundError(
                        "Whoops! File not found please enter correct file name: ")
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("File not found! Please enter correct file name:  ")
```

Any advice for me?